# What are some good vegetables or fruits that grow well only in afternoon sun

Tags: vegetables, sunlight

I live in the midwest United states and am curious as to what vegetables I could grow on my patio. it is west facing and thus the vegetables would only be able to get light from aroun 2 pm to 8pm. a

Comment: So they will have about 6 hours of direct sunlight?

Comment: @Rob yes. thats correct

Comment: Well we aren't supposed to answer questions in the comments but in general, with 6 hours of direct sunlight, you should be able to grow just about any vegetables.

Comment: Would I not need to worry about scorching? I know the afternoon sun is often the hottest.

Comment: @Rob forgot to tag you in my last comment

Comment: No I do not believe you will, maybe, but probobly not. If it looks like they are being burned you can always set up some shade.